# how to put the equations back to two-column mode?

Tags: equations

As shown in the picture, how to put the equations back to two-column mode?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{q_\mathrm{tot}=0}^{Q_A+Q_B-2}\sum_{q_A=0}^{q_\mathrm{tot}}{\textstyle\binom{Q_A-1}{q_A}\binom{Q_B-1}{q_B}}x^{q_\mathrm{tot}},
\end{equation}

$ cypher1 = MATCH (c:Product)-[r1:requiredProcess]->(d:Process) where c.ProductName = 'Product1' WITH COUNT(DISTINCT(d)) as number RETURN 'Process Number:'
$
where $Q_A=q_A+N_A$ and $Q_B=q_B+N_B$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are in two column but have no allowed break points so the line can not break, use a multi-line aligment from `amsmath` also do not use math italic for words use `\mathrm{requiredProcess}` (or \mathit{requiredProcess}` never `$requiredProcess$ as the default font designed to make it look like a product of 1-letter variables

Answer (score 2):

I hope that with this kind of code it has answered your question.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[3][1]
\begin{equation}
\sum_{q_{\mathrm{tot}=0}}^{Q_A+Q_B-2}\sum_{q_A=0}^{q_{\mathrm{tot}}}{\binom{Q_A-1}{q_A}\binom{Q_B-1}{q_B}}x^{q_{\mathrm{tot}}}
\end{equation}
 
\begin{verbatim}
  cypher1 = MATCH (c:Product)-
  [r1:requiredProcess]->(d:Process)
  where c.ProductName 
  = 'Product1' WITH COUNT(DISTINCT(d))
  as number RETURN 'Process Number:'
\end{verbatim}

where $Q_A=q_A+N_A$ and $Q_B=q_B+N_B$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but as I assume it is done manually, is there a solution to create a new line?

Comment: @James I have not understood. What new line? You, above and below, can write all.